# Why deserialize a tree?

Tags: performance, serialization, tree

Assume that one has built a tree (lets say it's binary if you like), and the tree has been serialized for one reason or other (so stored as a Matrix for example), and finally that it is known no new nodes will be added to the tree.

Here is my question: Why bother deserializing? I can see that if one wants to add new nodes this might be important, but otherwise it seems operations on the serial tree should be just as fast as if the tree were stored in a traditional pointer like structure.

I wouldn't even consider this a question worth asking, but there seems to be a large amount of interest in doing the deserializing, so there must be some motivation for it.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the downvote here is for. Still rather confused.

Answer (score 2):

1. Locality of reference.  Consolidating the tree into an contiguous array should improve cache performance.
2. Memory savings.  Tree structures are naturally pointer-heavy, which could be significant overhead if the data being stored aren't much larger than the pointers.

Comment: That seems to argue *against* deserializing, not in favor of it

Comment: Harold seems to be correct? Surely these are both reasons not to rebuild it with pointers.